# iOS: Tapjoy fullscreen ad open multiple screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, tapjoy

i'm trying to use Tapjoy for my apps and i'm using the following code

```
-(void)getTapJoyAd{
    [Tapjoy getFullScreenAd];

    // A notification method must be set to retrieve the fullscreen ad object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(getFullScreenAd:)
                                                 name:TJC_FULL_SCREEN_AD_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(fullscreenAdClosed:)
                                                 name:TJC_VIEW_CLOSED_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];

    // This method requests the tapjoy server for current virtual currency of the user.
    [Tapjoy getTapPoints];
    // A notification method must be set to retrieve the points.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getUpdatedPoints:) name:TJC_TAP_POINTS_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
}
```

the problem is when i recall the method again it opens two screens together .. 
the more i call this method the more screens open up..

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? - You might also want to include the code for methods `getFullScreenAd` and `fullscreenAdClosed`

Comment: i did implement them this is not the problem.. the problem is that .. whenever i call this method it open multiple ads as many as i call it.. it means when i call it 3 times it gives me 3 fullscreen ads.. what i need is a way to deallocate this

Comment: So you are saying that the first time you call this you get 1 advert shown, the second time you get 2 adverts shown (so a total of 3 including the first time) and the thrid time you call it you get another 3 so a total of 6 over all method calls?

Comment: not exactly second time i got 2 ads only third time i got 3 ads .. and so on

Comment: You need to remove an Observer somewhere in your code. Did you try ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the problem is how many times your `notification` is observed then your method is executing. So one way you can prevent the issue is once `notification` is posted and observed then  remove your `notification observer`. Also it depends on your code as well, that how you are dealing with `notification` part. So try to `remove observer` and check below:-

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:TJC_FULL_SCREEN_AD_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:TJC_VIEW_CLOSED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:TJC_TAP_POINTS_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
}
```